# Table Range not resizing after FilterCopy with Advanced Filter

Tags: excel, vba, range, excel-tables, listobject

I'm copying data using Advanced Filter, from one workbook table to a different workbook table. The copying works absolutely fine, but the output table does not resize the range to include the new data when it's entered.
I've tried the code below (and other code) to get the table to resize the range, but it's not doing anything. It's not giving an error either, just running through the code.

This is the last part of the code that's supposed to resize the table:

```
 With tblFiltered
            .Resize .Range(myLastRow, tblFiltered.HeaderRowRange.Count)
    End With
```

I'm including some more code, so you can see what the variables are set to.

```
'Copy Filtered data to specified tables
Dim tblFiltered As ListObject
Dim copyToRng As Range, SDCRange As Range

'DERANGED
'Store Filtered table in variable
Set tblFiltered = wb.Worksheets("Deranged with SOH").ListObjects("Table_Deranged_with_SOH")

'Remove Filtered table Filters
tblFiltered.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

'Set Copy to range on Filtered sheet table
Set copyToRng = tblFiltered.HeaderRowRange
Set SDCRange = MainWB.Worksheets(2).ListObjects("Table_SDCdata").Range

'Use Advanced Filter
SDCRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=DerangedCrit, CopyToRange:=copyToRng, Unique:=False

'Resize filtered table to include new data
With wb.Worksheets("Deranged with SOH").Cells
        'find last row of source data cell range
        myLastRow = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

 End With

With tblFiltered
        .Resize .Range(myLastRow, tblFiltered.HeaderRowRange.Count)
End With
```

I've tried using `.currentregion` but that didn't do anything either.
I'll be using the above code for multiple tables, to copy and then resize and change every week. So hard coding the values for resizing is not an option.

The 
`myLastRow` variable calculates correctly to a value (number of the last row), as do the `tblFiltered.HeaderRowRange.Count` (14 in this instance).

Not sure where I'm going wrong, if someone has any insight, that'll be helpful, thanks.

Comment: https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2015/04/30/excel-table-doesnt-expand-for-new-data/  (though that may not work when updating with VBA) or try converting your table to a regular range and then back to a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that you are giving the `Resize` method of `Table` object a `Range` object that is not what you'd expect it to be

in fact,

```
.Range(myLastRow, tblFiltered.HeaderRowRange.Count)
```

is actually returing the cell `myLastRow -1` rows and `tblFiltered.HeaderRowRange.Count` columns off the referenced table first cell ...

Then, you should code as follows:

```
With tbl
    .Resize .HeaderRowRange.Resize(myLastRow - .HeaderRowRange.Rows(1).row + 1)
End With
```

that is feeding the `Resize` method of `Table` object with a `Range` object obtained as the referenced table header range resized as many rows as to reach your `myLastRow` row

Comment: Unfortunetly, still, nothing is happening if I change the code to the above...

Comment: since it worked in my tests, it must be something in the overall background. 1) have you any `On Error Resume Next`? 2) place a breakpoint (F9) at `With tbl` code line, run the code and once the code stops there use Immediate Window (ctrl-g to pop it out) and type `?myLastRow, tbl.HeaderRowRange.Address, tbl.HeaderRowRange.Rows(1).row` press enter and see the outcome.

Comment: I do have an `On Error Resume Next` earlier in the code, where it runs through the tables and rename 2 columns if it finds it. The Immediate window shows `6466         $B$12:$O$12    12 `. So the `6466` is the correct count for the rows, `$B$12:$O$12` is the correct header indication for the table.

Comment: Remove that OERN statament and re run the code. Just to see if there's some error shadowing the actual problem

Comment: It works! when I remove that OERN statement...Thank you!. So how would be best to rename those columns before copying the data, if the OERN seems to be the problem?

Comment: You are welcome. You may then consider marking answer as accepted to direct future readers, too.  As for your last question, it's up to where that OERN was placed and what error it shadowed. But that should be the matter of a brand new question that I invite you to post along with_ all_ relevant code

Answer (score 0):

This might help, just shows how to copy rows from one table to another by adding rows to the second table.

```
Sub x()

Dim t1 As ListObject, t2 As ListObject, r As Range, n As Long

Set t1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Set t2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

Set r = t1.ListRows(4).Range.Resize(2) 'range to be copied, 2 rows to table 1
n = t2.Range.Rows.Count 'initial count of rows in table 2

t2.Resize t2.Range.Resize(t2.Range.Rows.Count + r.Rows.Count) 'resize table2 by number of rows in range to be copied

r.Copy t2.Range.Cells(n + 1, 1) 'copy and paste at original end so should fit

End Sub
```

Not sure why you're referring to `HeaderRowRange` which is only the header?

Comment: I'll give it a try. I use the `HeaderRowRange` to get the count for the columns. The range "help" that pops up asks for Range(RowIndex, ColumnIndex). Would I have to specify the column and row for both `RowIndex` as well as `ColumnIndex`? I'm confused about why the table doesn;t automatically resize the rang in the first place when the data is added...

Answer (score 0):

If your table is bounded by (and does not contain) empty rows/columns then you should be able to do this:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable")

tbl.Resize tbl.Range(1).CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but unfortunately I have one column that's empty, so .currentregion is not going to work.

Comment: Are you allowed empty headers in a listobject?

Comment: Tim, not that I'm aware of. I could be wrong but If it's in a table, the table will automatically name a column to 'column 1', 'column2', etc.

Comment: So i'd have expected Currentregion to work, since the column header would "bridge" the empty data column...   No matter - seems like you have the fix.

Answer (score 0):

### DataBodyRange vs HeaderRowRange

The name says it all: `HeaderRowRange` is used for one ROW of headers. You want to write your data below to the `DataBodyRange`. The first empty row is calculated like this:

`tbl.DataBodyRange.Row + tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`.

The first column can be calculated like this: `tbl.DataBodyRange.Column`.

So the first empty cell below a table (in the 1st column) is calculated like this:

```
Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Row + tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tbl.DataBodyRange.Column)
```

---

**The Code**

```
Sub DBR()

    'Copy Filtered data to specified tables
    Dim tblFiltered As ListObject
    Dim copyToRng As Range, SDCRange As Range

    'DERANGED
    'Store Filtered table in variable
    Set tblFiltered = wb.Worksheets("Deranged with SOH").ListObjects("Table_Deranged_with_SOH")

    'Remove Filtered table Filters
    tblFiltered.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'Set Copy to range on Filtered sheet table
    ' '.Parent.Parent' means 'up two levels' i.e. the worksheet.
    ' (first 'level up' is the table)
    With tblFiltered.DataBodyRange
        Set copyToRng = .Parent.Parent.Cells(.Row + .Rows.Count, .Column)
    End With

    Set SDCRange = MainWB.Worksheets(2).ListObjects("Table_SDCdata").Range

    'Use Advanced Filter
    SDCRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=DerangedCrit, CopyToRange:=copyToRng, Unique:=False

End Sub
```